# How to read an XML file with out DTD or schema in Java

Tags: java, xml

We have an XML file, generated from LDAP. It does start with Docroot, but there is no DTD declaration. We tried generating DTD, but there are simply too many variants and we were told every one else process the file manually (with out DTD or schema). 
We know what we need to read from XML and the format of the document will not change. 
So, my question is what is the simplest way to read this XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). It doesn't require a schema. You can use annotations and/or naming conventions to drive the mapping. Since you don't have a schema you might get some quirky behavior if your xml is malformed, but its better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

[SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) probably.

Although you might conceder using [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) or [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) (which I very much recommend).

Comment: How do you generate the JAXB bindings without schema?

Comment: @nsfyn55 I don't really know why the misconception that you can't use JAXB without a schema is so common ... http://duckranger.com/2011/06/jaxb-without-a-schema/

Comment: hmmmm fair enough. I was just wondering. I guess the answer is that you can bind, but you can't generate the artifacts. You'd have to write them by hand.

Comment: @nsfynn55 Yes indeed inconvenient, but nothing is nice when you don't have a schema anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Most non-validating XML parsers will read your XML file even when it doesn't declare a DTD. The list is long and varied but as nsyfn55 suggested you can use Xstream - it's very fast.